# Can't apply checkbox properties to for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

Alright so I hope Im just missing something easy. Basically I am making a todo list where I want to have a checkbox appear with each list item (this works). When users click on the checkbox, the textDecoration = "line-through" is supposed to go through the listItem class. Meaning a line goes through the todo task the person creates. Here is the code I am mainly working with:

```
function show() {
var todos = get_todos();

var html = '<ul>';
for(var i=0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<span><li class="listItem" style="float:left;">' + todos[i] + '</li><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox">' + '<button class="remove" id="' + i  + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><br/>';
};
html += '</ul>';

document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
for (var i=0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
};

////////////////////////////////////
//Everything above here works. Below is the checkbox issue

var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

for (var i=0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        listItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }else {
        listItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
};}
```

Where I'm at now is if I create an onClick function in the original checkbox, I can use that if/else statement and it kind of works. It will not work if I set the checkBox/listItems variables using document.getElementsByClassName but it will work if I use document.getElementById. The problem is that it only works on the first task that the user creates and none of the other ones created after. Im assuming that is either because Ids only work for one element (unlike a class that works for multiple) or because its not cycling through a for loop like it is in the code above.

**TL/DR** Basically when I run the code above I keep getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textDecoration' of undefined
    at show (todo.js:57)
    at todo.js:75".

I dont get this error when I make a separate function for the checkbox and use elementbyid instead of elementsbyclass (changing the id/class of the html section above too)

I really want to get those line-through effects working on all tasks, not just the first one. Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks everyone!

Comment: you have to use checkBox[i] and find appropriate listItem[i] to set the textDecoration, currently you are checking the entire list (checkBox)

Comment: `listItem` is a collection of elements, `style` is not a property of a collection of elements, so style is `undefined`, thats why you can't set `textDecoration` on it. You must iterate over each `listItem` element to set properties this way. (the same is valid to `checkBox` (it's a collection))

Comment: So when I try something along the lines of                                                         
`var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

for (var i=0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked == true){
        listItems[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }else {
        listItems[i].style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
};}
`I dont get any console errors but the checkbox doesnt do anything when clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would accomplish this with css instead of javascript (that's generally my rule, when possible). In this case you have to make one small change to your markup: since there's no `previous-sibling` selector, you'll have to put the `input`s before the corresponding `li`s, but since the `li`s are `float:left` it still renders exactly the same.

```css
input:checked + li {
  text-decoration:line-through;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<span><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox"><li class="listItem" style="float:left;">foo</li><button class="remove" id="' + i  + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><br/>
<span><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox"><li class="listItem" style="float:left;">bar</li><button class="remove" id="' + i  + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><br/>
<span><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox"><li class="listItem" style="float:left;">baz</li><button class="remove" id="' + i  + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><br/>
</ul>
```

Comment: Honestly, this is perfect. I was set on trying to do this in javascript but css is much more simple. This was really well done and I think I was too far down the rabbit hole to notice css could make this easier. Thank you very much and everyone for the effort!

Comment: If it was valid HTML then it might be considered perfect; but as the only valid child of a [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) or [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol) is an [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li) element (no, `<div>`, `<span>` and `<a>` elements are *not* valid children) then wrap the contents that you wish to `strike-through` in a container element (within the `<li>`) as an adjacent sibling of the `<input>`: `<li><input type="checkbox"><div><!-- other contents --></div></li>`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function show() {
  var todos = get_todos();

  var html = '<ul>';
  for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++) {
    html += '<span><li class="listItem" style="float:left;">' + todos[i] + '</li><input class="checkBox" type="checkbox">' + '<button class="remove" id="' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></span><br/>';
  };
  html += '</ul>';

  document.getElementById('todos').innerHTML = html;

  var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('remove');
  for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', remove);
  };

  ////////////////////////////////////
  //Everything above here works. Below is the checkbox issue

  var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
  var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

  for (var i = 0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox[i].checked == true) {
      listItem[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    } else {
      listItem[i].style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
  };
}
```

You probably missed the index in the listItem and checkBox array

Comment: hmm, so when I do that I don't get any console error but nothing happens when I click the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that `checkBox` is an array-like object.  I think you know that as when you wrote the code you look at checkBox.length, however you then failed to index into the array.

You have:

```
var checkBox = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
var listItem = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

for (var i=0; i < checkBox.length; i++) {
    if (checkBox.checked == true){
        listItem.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }else {
        listItem.style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
};}
```

To make it clear I've pluralised the names where needed, as well as adding the index reference:

```
var checkBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName("checkBox");
var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("listItem");

for (var i=0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
    if (checkBoxes[i].checked == true){
        listItems[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";
    }else {
        listItems[i].style.textDecoration = "none";
    }
};}
```

Comment: Okay, when I try using your code with the index references I dont have any console errors. However, nothing happens when I click the checkbox.

Comment: Your code sets the properties of the list items at the time the code is run.  It does not create a permanent binding of any kind.  You need to add an event on the check boxed which then triggers the code above.  If you end up needing to do a lot of this then you might like to consider using a framework, Vuejs, React, or similar (there are many but these are probably the two most popular right now) to deal with such bindings for you.